# is there anyone help me about this p2 ejabberd error?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, p2

Greeting.
I'm using a P2 push proxy for sending notifications through FCM and APNS but when I try to send from the Application I receive this error

failed to enable push. invalid response from app server cHn-x-y4T4CWeKqnVr0Dp4:APA91bE70iKq4XKRHZh6rRYnqWbgFZcCCPLclauJRF1qtP5JUmHxjjzyROPcADt0wfAlvLGuzV_aVMMgLT7SEAQ9onpKY_XKBmYVSIhJ07r26g9wSvqzCf5wRP_IfFCGFmgtrBgtwpr_de94b44f12fc91abNo hook has processed this command

and in ejabberd logs it shows
<0.1875.0>@mod_push:notify/5:539 push.tigase.im rejected notification for +244123456789@chat.woooo.world (01#0411330DA6D7BC8BBC11EE19F653DB6BF73D7935E4332FB86D119857A0F3473C), disabling push: XMPP error condition: item-not-found (<item-not-found) (cancel)

this error.
what's the issue?